# How to get more readable code on performing validation on object instead of using constant 'AndAlso'?

Tags: vb.net, validation

I'm currently working on a company project where I need to check if our API receives an object with all blank variables, and subsequently give back an error code to the API user.

We have a model that has multiple objects within it (in this case, document object), which if it is left out just passes an object with blank default values for their properties (blank strings, '0' for integers, '0001-01-01' date...).

In short, I need to find a more readable way of checking these without using constant `AndAlso` like the below example, since there is around 11 fields in the object:

```
If guid.isNullOrEmpty AndAlso content.isNullOrEmpty AndAlso fileName Is String.Empty Then 
   Set Validation Message
   Return False
End If
```

I would do: 
`If object.Document.IsNothing`, but the object is never received completely `null`. I need any potentially more readable ways. Examples that other languages do is much appreciated as well. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of efficiency you are talking of? For sure there is no more efficient way than that in terms of cpu cycles.

Comment: I know that it will short circuit if it doesn't fulfill any part of the statement, but it just seems like it might not be the best way to do this, especially since it will end up with a huge single line `if` statement. I suppose it is not so much efficiency as alternate ways to write it...

Comment: Maybe you are asking for a more concise or  more readable way. Write a method `IsDocumentValid(doc as Document) As Boolean`. On this way you encapsulate the  logic there and can write: `Return IsDocumentValid(object.Document)`

Comment: That probably would be a more appropriate question, I'll edit the post to reflect this. Readability is one of the main things. I do have a `IsDocumentValid` call, but having this on a single line inside looks messy. I suppose it might be unavoidable

Comment: You can put the IF statement on multiple line, doesn't need to be one big line.

Comment: As @the_lotus says, break up your condition onto multiple lines.  Just put a line break after each `AndAlso` and everything can then line up vertically and be very readable.

Comment: @SeanS: _"I do have a IsDocumentValid call, but having this on a single line inside looks messy"_ I don't get this. You can also store the result in a variable. `Dim isDocValid = IsDocumentValid(object.Document) If isDocValid Then Message = "Something" Return isDocValid`

Comment: @the_lotus I could put it on multiple lines for readability, but my question is that is there a better way than writing it that way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I meant that I have a `isDocValida` function call, but having the checks within that function using all those `AndAlso` look messy.

Comment: You make it readable with `Dim ok As Boolean = True`.  Set it to false with multiple IF-statements, each testing the detail you might be unhappy about.   Easy to debug as well.  And easy to provide each condition with a custom error message that clarifies the mishap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one line condition looks messy split it to many `if` statements with return if condition fails.

```
Public Function IsValid() As Boolean
    If guid.isNullOrEmpty Then 
        Return False
    End If

    If content.isNullOrEmpty Then 
        Return False
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

Alternative approach can be to have a collection of predicates

```
Public Class DocumentValidator
    Private ReadOnly _validations As List(Func(Of Document, Boolean))        

    Public Sub New()
        _validations = New List(Func(Of Document, Boolean)) From
        {
            Function(doc) doc.guid.isNullOrEmpty = False,
            Function(doc) doc.content.isNullOrEmpty = False,
            Function(doc) doc.fileName IsNot String.Empty,
        }
    End Sub

    Public Function Validate(document As Document) As Boolean
        Return _validations.All(Function(validate) validate(document))
    End Function
End Class

// Use Validator
Dim validator = New DocumentValidator()
If validator.Validate(document) Then
    ' Do something
Else
    ' Show error message
End If
```

Comment: I like the collection of predicates, that looks much better than a single line. I'll put this into practice, thanks!